# Which threads in a block form a warp?

Tags: cuda, gpu

In a 2-d or 3-d CUDA block, how are threads grouped into warps?  My assumption is that they iterate first by x, then y, then z.  For example, in threads with `<z,y,x>`, `<0,0,[0-31]>` is a warp, and so is `<0,1,[0-31]>`, etc. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that is correct.  Threads are grouped first by X, then Y, then Z (thread coordinates) when creating warps (groups of 32 threads that execute together).  This has implications for good coalescing: you will want to arrange your usage of thread coordinates in matrix subscripts so that warp-adjacent threads (i.e. in X coordinates, typically) will access adjacent elements in the matrix (by using threadIdx.x or a derivative in the most rapidly varying matrix dimension.  We typically want `data[z][y][x]`, not `data[x][y][z]`

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that is why I was asking the question. Trying to optimize my performance with coalescing.

Comment: visual profiler can also help with indications of memory utilization efficiency if you run the kernel memory profiling operation.